# Differential equation polar coordinates: $\frac{d^2 r}{d \theta^2} + 4r = 5\sin(3\theta)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can the following differential equation be solved?

$\frac{d^2 r}{d \theta^2} + 4r = 5\sin(3\theta)$ for $\frac{\pi}{5} \le \theta \le \frac{3 \pi}{5}$ that satisfies $\frac{d r}{d \theta} = - 2$ when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}, r=1$.

Comment: Same way as you would solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 4y = 5\sin(3x)$ Being polar (at least in terms of this case) is not a problem. Solve as you would any other second order non-homogenous linear equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solve first the homogenous differential equation:
$$ r'' + 4r = 0 $$
which have general solution:
$$ r(\theta)= c_1 \cos(2\theta) + c_2 \sin(2\theta) $$

The general solution to the differential equation:
$$ r''+4r = 5\sin(3\theta) $$
is the general solution to the homogenous equation plus an offset, a particular solution to this equation. We can find a particular solution to this equation by the method of undetermined coefficients - given the form $5\sin(3\theta)$, our particular solution is of the form:
\begin{align*}
r &= A\cos(3\theta)+B\sin(3\theta) \\
r'' &= -9A\cos(3\theta) - 9B\sin(3\theta) \\[5pt]
r''+4r &= -5A\cos(3\theta)-5B\sin(3\theta) =5\sin(3\theta)
\end{align*}
So our particular solution corresponds to $A = 0, B=-1$.

Putting this all together, the general solution to
$$ r'' + 4r = 5\sin(3\theta) $$
is:
$$ r(\theta) = c_1 \cos(2\theta) + c_2\sin(2\theta) - \sin(3\theta) $$
We are given that
\begin{align*}
r(\pi/2) &= 1 & r'(\pi/2) &= -2 \\
-c_1 + 1 &= 1 & -2c_2 &= -2 \\
c_1 &= 0 & c_2 &= 1
\end{align*}
So the solution to the differential equation, with the conditions given is:
$$ r(\theta) = \sin(2\theta) - \sin(3\theta) $$

Comment: Thank you very much! But how did you spot so easily the solutions $\cos(2\theta)$ and $\sin(2\theta)$ for $r″+4r=0$?

Comment: Let $r(\theta) = c \exp(s\theta)$ and solve for $s$.

Comment: @harlem (I suggest looking at an ODE text, this is a fundamental result one should know in solving ODEs). The differential equation $y'' + 4y = 0$ is a second-order constant-coeffecient linear differential equation, so you solve it by solving the characteristic equation $r^2 + 4r = 0$, which has solutions $r = \pm 2i$. In general, the solutions $r_1, r_2$ to the characteristic equation correspond to linearly independent solutions $e^{r_1 t}, e^{r_2 t}$ to the differential equation - manipulation of coefficients shows that we can remove complex terms and reduce to $\cos(2 t), \sin(2t)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\totald[2]{r}{\theta} + 4r = 5\sin\pars{3\theta}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\mbox{Define}\quad \varphi \equiv \totald{r}{\theta} + 2\ic r\quad
\mbox{such that}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{r} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 2}\,\Im\pars{\varphi}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\totald[2]{r}{\theta}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\totald{\varphi}{r} - 2\ic\,\totald{r}{\theta}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{r} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over 2}\,\ic\pars{\totald{r}{\theta} - \varphi}}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm]
&\mbox{Then,}\quad
5\sin\pars{3\theta} =
\bracks{\totald{\varphi}{\theta} - 2\ic\,\totald{r}{\theta}} +
4\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,\ic\pars{\totald{r}{\theta} - \varphi}} =
\totald{\varphi}{\theta} -2\ic\varphi
\\ &----------------------------------
\\ &
\expo{-2\ic\theta}\pars{\totald{\varphi}{\theta} -2\ic\varphi} =
5\expo{-2\ic\theta}\sin\pars{3\theta}
\implies
\totald{\pars{\expo{-2\ic\theta}\varphi}}{\theta} =
5\expo{-2\ic\theta}\sin\pars{3\theta}
\\ &----------------------------------
\\ &
\expo{-2\ic\theta}\varphi =
5\int\expo{-2\ic\theta}\sin\pars{3\theta}\,\dd\theta + A =
-\,{5 \over 2}\,\expo{\ic\theta} - {1 \over 2}\,\expo{-5\ic\theta} + A
\\ &---------------------------------------
\\ &
\varphi =
-\,{5 \over 2}\,\expo{3\ic\theta} - {1 \over 2}\,\expo{-3\ic\theta} + A\expo{2\ic\theta}
\implies
\bbx{r = -\,{5 \over 4}\,\sin\pars{3\theta} +
{1 \over 4}\,\sin\pars{3\theta} + {1 \over 2}\,\Im\pars{A\expo{2\ic\theta}}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{A}$ is a *constant*. $\ds{A \in \mathbb{C}}$. The general solution can be written as follows:

$$
\bbx{r = -\sin\pars{3\theta} + a\cos\pars{2\theta} + b\sin\pars{2\theta}}\,,
\qquad a, b \in \mathbb{R}
$$

> $\ds{r\pars{\pi \over 2} = 1 \implies -1 - a = 1 \implies a = -2}$

> $\ds{\left.\totald{r}{\theta}\right\vert_{\ \theta\ =\ \pi/2} = -2
> \implies -2b = -2 \implies b = 1}$

---

$$
\bbx{r = -\sin\pars{3\theta} - 2\cos\pars{2\theta} + \sin\pars{2\theta}}\,,
\qquad a, b \in \mathbb{R}
$$